# version `GLIBC_2.33' not found

Tags: linux, entity-framework, .net-core, glibc, manjaro

I'm using .net core on Linux specifically Manjaro 20.2.1, I'm learning .net core, I want to use EF commands, but it's slightly different how its works on Linux, I had installed the dotnet-ef tool whit this command:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.3
```

So when I try to run **donet ef** throws me this error:

```
/home/$USERNAME/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef: /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
```

But it seems that the GLIBC version that it's installed on my distro is: ***2.33-3***, and its seems that the version that it's looking for it's specifically the 2.33.

How I can get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that something in *dotnet* depends on GLIBC 2.33 but *dotnet* is tied to **core18** which is using GLIBC 2.27.

```
λ snap list
Name                Version          Rev    Tracking       Publisher    Notes
core                16-2.48.2.1      10823  latest/stable  canonical✓   core
core18              20210128         1988   latest/stable  canonical✓   base
dotnet-sdk          5.0.103          112    latest/stable  dotnetcore✓  classic

λ file /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: symbolic link to libc-2.27.so
```

Comment: Hi, I just runt the command but ist'n work throws me this log: /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:: cannot open `/snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:' (No such file or directory)

Comment: Did you forget to remove a trailing colon? Try this `file /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Comment: this is the output of the last command: /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: symbolic link to libc-2.27.so

Comment: But still getting the same problem

Comment: Oh I mean it's not a fix. My theory is `dotnet` depends on the system's `Glibc 2.32` and to fix it your system must have `glibc 2.32` but Manjaro comes with `2.33-4` on the stable branch. Apparently `dotnet` aims at Ubuntu 20.10 with its `glibc 2.32` (interesting Ubuntu 20.04 has `2.31`, so the snap won't work on it?)

Comment: Oh I see, Do you think if I download dotnet-runtime from arch repo, could it work?

Comment: Hey, thank you,it was that you suspect, the snap dotnet package, doesn't really work well with manjaro, so I uninstall it and install the one from the repos, and now its working!

Comment: Had the same error on a snap that is based on core 20